# How can I apply a function on every element of a list?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, netcdf

I import all files into a list.

```
library(ncdf4)

list <- list.files(path=".", pattern="*test*", full.names=TRUE) 
dat = lapply(list, nc_open)
```

Now, `dat` is a `large list` of 10 elements. Each element has 15 NetCDF variables, out of which I only want to extract one.

I can extract variables from each element individually using this:

```
dat1var <- ncvar_get(dat[[1]], "temp")
dat2var <- ncvar_get(dat[[2]], "temp")
..
dat10var <- ncvar_get(dat[[10]], "temp")
```

How can I do this using lapply or some other method?

I tried this

```
lapply(dat, function(x) svar <- ncvar_get(dat[[x]], ncvar))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lapply(dat, ncvar_get, "temp")
```

You can chain `lapply`s:

```
lapply(lapply(list, nc_open), ncvar_get, "temp")
```

which is also

```
list %>% lapply(nc_open) %>% lapply(ncvar_get, "temp")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this young apprentice

```
library(purrr)
purrr:map(dat,c(i,"temp"))
```

Comment: All `NULL` values unfortunately

Comment: try again now buddy